# Send html text as attachment to sendgrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have text stored as html in the database. I want to convert that text to a file that I can send as an attachment using sendgrid. Does anyone know how? Here's what I have so far

```
         var body = {
        subject: book.title + " test Original",
        personalizations:
            [{
                to: [{email: to,}]
            }],
        content: [{type: "text/plain", value: book.title + " book summary"}],
        from: {email: 'info@test.com', name: 'test Team'},
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: book.id + ".html",
                content: btoa(book.body),
                type: 'text/html',
                disposition: 'attachment'
            }
        ]
    };
    this.sendMail(body)
```

I want to do this using node and javascript. I updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a suitable extension to the provided filename (eg **booksummary.html**)
- Replace the type value with the correct MIME type (**text/html**)

Refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) for file extension to MIME mapping.

Comment: What should data_base64 be? Thanks :)

Comment: Use `data_base64 = window.btoa(htmlcontent)` , where htmlcontent would be your html text

Comment: It's nodejs. I don't have access to window. What should I do?

Comment: nvm there's a npm code for it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/btoa

Comment: I tried 
                    filename: book.id + ".html",
                    content: btoa(book.body),
                    type: 'text/html',
                    disposition: 'attachment'

Comment: but kindle does not recognize the document as html